# Ruby extract sub-string from string between two question marks?

Tags: ruby, string

Let's say I have a string like this:

`"What is your first name? My first name is John. What is your last name? My last name is Doe."`

How can I extract the string between the question marks? The output should be:

`" My first name is John. What is your last name"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the split function, then access the one in the middle, which is the text between the question marks.

If you want the leading space, you can simply do this

```
string.split('?')[1]
```

To remove the leading space you can call the `lstrip` method.

```
string.split('?')[1].lstrip
```

Comment: It would be more efficient if you pass `3` as the second argument to `split`.

Comment: This returns a leading blank space, which is what the OP asked for. If leading spaces are not wanted, a slight mod: `string.split(/\?\s*/)[1] #=> "My first name is John. What is your last name".

Comment: Yep, there is also an `lstrip` method for removing the leading space.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest passing a regex to `String#slice` - it will return a (sub)string matching the regex, or `nil` if there is no match in the string upon which you call it.

You might generally find http://rubular.com/ helpful for getting your regexes right.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [String#gsub](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) with a regex

```
"What is your first name? My first name is John. What is your last name? My last name is Doe.".
  gsub(/^.*\?(.*)\?.*$/,"\\1")
#=> " My first name is John. What is your last name"
```

and a lot of other answers. May I suggest to make you question a bit clearer?